# if is.null or another value R

Tags: r

How would I make this comparison in R?

```
if (is.null(a)| a == 'LAST') {
    # do something
    }
```

If the `a` is `NULL` this fails, throwing the error:

```
Error in if (a == "LAST") { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

How could I work around this?

Comment: Use the (logical OR) || operator instead of the (bitwise OR) |.

Comment: Is "LAST" a value?